# VBA - Ignore first row in a named column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple check that I want to do where I check a specific named column for a value but ignoring the first row (as these are the column titles).

I thought that I could combine the offset function with the range but it doesn't seem to work:

```
If MyF.CountIf(Range("Deleted").Offset(1), "Deleted") > 0 Then
   MsgBox ("Please delete the order from the list")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Anyone with a solution please?

Comment: how exactly it doesn't work? Have you tried debugging? Especially `Range("Deleted").Address` and `Range("Deleted").Offset(1).Address` would be interesting.

Comment: When I run the code as shown in my opening post, I receive the error "1004 - Application-defined or obect-defined error'. When I add ".address" it gives a "type mismatch"

Comment: How do you declare MyF? It has to be `WorksheetFunction`

Comment: yes indeed, and it works if I don't add the offset function. The declaration is: Dim MyF As WorksheetFunction
Set MyF = WorksheetFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming `Range("Deleted")` is an entire column in a Worksheet and you want to get the Range that is the entire column less the cell in row 1, then you can use `Range("Deleted").Resize(Range("Deleted").Parent.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1)` which would make your code

```
If MyF.CountIf(Range("Deleted").Resize(Range("Deleted").Parent.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1), "Deleted") > 0 Then
   MsgBox ("Please delete the order from the list")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

... however, it's hard to know whether this is valid code without knowing what type of object `MyF` is.

If you are starting with an entire column and then trying to offset it down by 1 row then your error is because that new range includes a cell that doesn't exist (ie the cell on row 1048577 on modern versions of Excel)

Comment: JohnM you rock!! It worked, thank you very much :) edit: cannot cast an upvote as my reputation is apparently too low but nevertheless thanks through this comment

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.